# UnknownHostException for https url

Tags: dns, httpsurlconnection

I'm doing

```
 HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL("https", "www.sec.gov", 443, "/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcurrent&CIK=&type=SC%2013D&company=&dateb=&owner=include&start=0&count=40&output=atom").openConnection();
 InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();
```

but it fails with

java.net.UnknownHostException: [www.sec.gov](http://www.sec.gov)
at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:220)
at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403)
at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:289)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:173)
at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:182)
at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:474)
at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:569)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.(HttpsClient.java:265)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:372)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1187)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1071)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1069)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivilegedWithCombiner(AccessController.java:795)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1068)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1592)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$9.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1512)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$9.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1510)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivilegedWithCombiner(AccessController.java:795)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1509)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)

I'm successfully able to ping the host [www.sec.gov](http://www.sec.gov) or curl the url. Why is my Java program alone not working? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It is working today without doing any change. I suspect a host name DNS timeout may be the reason it didn't work before.